# IIS URL rewriting to redirect querystring addresses to MVC style path to preserve old links

Tags: url-rewriting, query-string, iis-7.5

I am trying to preserve old links such as index.php?pageid=123 to the now current /accounts/home. No part of the original URL has to be included in the redirect.

I have a big list of old page links and their new address. I thought it would be really simple to say index.php?pageid=123 = /accounts/home but I can't see how to do it. Most of the examples I see are the other way around whereby your site uses query string and you want your URLs to be SEO friendly. I'm using IIS 7.5 to rewrite.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it sorted and it wasn't that hard really. Just needed to add  the query string as a condition.

```
    <rules>
        <rule name="accounting" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="index1.php" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=accounts/accountsmain" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="business-services/accounting.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```